# Why is my extended header going into my body?

Tags: html, pug

Can someone tell me why, even though I am extending my head block the html that is generated goes into the body and not the header?

I have layout pug file setup like this (you can clearly see my head block is inside the head tag)

```
doctype html
html
  head
    block head
      title= title      
      link(rel='stylesheet', href='/css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css')
      script(type='text/javascript' src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.6.1/dist/jquery.min.js')    
      script(type='text/javascript' src='/js/lodash/lodash.js')
      script(type='text/javascript' src='/js/popper/popper.min.js')      
      script(type='text/javascript' src='/js/bootstrap/bootstrap.js')

  
  - var bodyClasses = [];
  block beforeBody 

  body(class=bodyClasses)
    block content
```

I have created a header in another pug file that extends the first file

```
append head 
    script(type='module' src="../javascripts/controllers/headerController.js")
    .container
        header.d-flex.flex-wrap.align-items-center.justify-content-center.justify-content-md-between.py-3.mb-4.border-bottom 
            a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm Hello
            .col-md-3.text-end 
                button.btn.btn-sm.btn-light#logOutBtn(type='button') Logout
```

finnaly I have a page pug file that extends the header pug like so:

```
extends header

append head
    script(type='module' src="./javascripts/controllers/adminController.js")

block beforeBody 
    - bodyClasses.push('bg-dark')
    - bodyClasses.push('py-3')
    - bodyClasses.push('text-white')

block content
 //page goes here
```

But for some reason this generates the html for the header in the body instead. Causing issues with how I want the background to display.

If it isn't obvious I'm trying to keep the header separate so I can have some pages that display it, and others that don't.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @Sean 's answer I have come up with a solution that works to get the effect I want.

I added a new block above my **content** block called **header**. Then header.pug I appended this block with the header HTML I previously had inside my **head** block. Just with the small change that I force the background color to be white.

```
body(class=bodyClasses)
    block header
    block content
```

```
extends layout

append head 
    script(type='module' src="../javascripts/controllers/headerController.js")

append header
    .bg-white
        .container
            header.d-flex.flex-wrap.align-items-center.justify-content-center.justify-content-md-between.py-3.mb-4.border-bottom 
                a.btn.btn-primary.btn-sm Hello
                .col-md-3.text-end 
                    button.btn.btn-sm.btn-light#logOutBtn(type='button') Logout
```

Answer (score 1):

It's invalid HTML to put `div`, `header`, `a`, etc. elements within the `head` element. Because your "head" block is nested within the `head` element, that where all the content in your second code block is going.

Many browsers will automatically try to move divs etc out of the `head` and into the `body` element, which is probably why you're seeing it in the body.

Comment: Ok yeah, looking it up it seems as if the head element is now just for meta data.  I believe back when I initially learned HTML (back in the early 2000's) it wasn't limited to just that.